# Extract object from the image

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I have images of license plates (images are cropped like these example images). I want to extract only plate from the input image.

I have applied OpenCV Canny Edge detector but I can't progress further. 
Can anyone help me please?

My final goal is to replace plate with my company logo.

License Plate image examples:

[image: License Plate]

[image]

Comment: Can you show us the code you have written so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of different approaches. If you have extracted edges with `cv2.Canny()` then you can extract contours with `cv2.findContours()`. Once you have that you can draw the plate out with `cv2.drawContours()` or make a mask of the contour are which you then add your logo etc.

Instead of Canny edge detection you can try to transform your cropped area to binary image with `cv2.threshold()` and the search for contours. You can even add some criterion to define the right contour like the area it occupies, perimeter of contour, height, lenght etc.

For example:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('license.png')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
_, threshold = cv2.threshold(gray,170,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
_, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(threshold, cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

for cnt in contours:
    size = cv2.contourArea(cnt)
    perimeter = cv2.arcLength(cnt,True)
    x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
    if 10000 > size > 1000 and w < 140 and h > 50 and perimeter < 360:
        cv2.drawContours(img, [cnt], 0, (255,255,255), -1)

cv2.imshow('img', img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Result:

[image]

[image]

Hope it helps a bit or gives you a new point of view on the problem. Cheers!